# Problem solving a second-order PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I am looking for numerical solutions for a class of equations of the type :

```
e = Derivative[2,0][ps][x,w]+(2/x)*Derivative[1,0][ps][x,w]-r[x,w]==0
```

With r a function that can vary but for the sake of example:

```
r[x_,w_]:=1-ps[x,w]/2
```

The boundary conditions are given at x=0 and x=1 by:

```
bc1=Derivative[1, 0][ps][0, w] == 0
bc2=Derivative[1, 0][ps][1, w] == (ps[1, w] - pc[w])
```

With pc being taken to be for illustration:

```
pc[w_] := 5*(1 - 0.01*w)
```

Mathematica returns an error message upon resolution:

```
NDSolve[{e, bc1, bc2}, ps, {x, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 10}]
```

At first I figured I was missing a boundary condition, but adding

```
bc3=ps[0, 0] == 0
```

does not seem to help. Any suggestions ?

Edit:

After changing to remove w from NDSolve parameters :

```
NDSolve[{e, bc1, bc2}, ps, {x, 0, 1}]
```

The error message comes as :

```
NDSolve::ndode: Input is not an ordinary differential equation. >>
```

Comment: You are missing brackets around ps in the equation for `e'.

Comment: The problem is that the set of equations are not a differential equation in $w$. Thus the error message from Mathematica.

Comment: @Fabian I took your advice and removed the w dependence in NDSolve (ans fixed a typo). I am now getting a different error message, as described in my edit.

Comment: Is ei1 supposed to be bc1, etc.?

Comment: As I see it, your boundary condition at x=1 depends on the value of `ps[1,w]`. I don't think `NDSolve` is going to be happy about that.

Comment: How did you remove `w`?  The way I did it gave me a trivial solution (ps = 0) with no error, which is probably not what you want.  Your code must be different, but I can't guess what you did.

Comment: @MichaelE2 re: bc1 etc, you are correct, sorry that was another typo which I fixed. When I say I removed w, I meant I removed it from NDSolve, as in the edit.

Comment: @KellenMyers I have been wondering about that, but I have tested similar conditions on simpler differential equations and had no issues.

Comment: The error means that `e` is not an ODE (it's partial diff. equation).  You need to remove `w` from the equations, too, if you remove it from `NDSolve` (if that's even possible). -- Something like Kellen Myer's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Eliminating `w` entirely from the `ps` function (treating it more like a parameter) seems to have some benefit:

```
r[x_, w_] = 1 - ps[x]/2
pc[w_] = 5*(1 - 0.01*w)
DSolve[
 {
  Derivative[2][ps][x] + (2/x)*Derivative[1][ps][x] - r[x, w] == 0,
  Derivative[1][ps][0] == 0,
  Derivative[1][ps][1] == (ps[1] - pc[w])
 },
 ps,
 {x, 0, 1}
]
```

This returns a function that I've simplified a bit:

```
f[x_, w_] = 
 (2. x - 0.0656427 (-60. + 1. w) Sin[x/Sqrt[2]])/x
```

Unfortunately, `DSolve` also kicks out the `Solve::ifun` error, meaning this solution may not be correct.

I've tested the boundary conditions, they seem okay:

```
Limit[Derivative[1, 0][f][x, w], x -> 0]
(* Output: 0. *)

Chop[Simplify[Derivative[1, 0][f][1, w] - (f[1, w] - pc[w])]]
(* Output: 0. *)
```

And with some tweaking, I think we can also double check the PDE:

```
r2[x, w] = 1 - f[x, w]/2;
Chop[FullSimplify[
 Derivative[2, 0][f][x, w] + (2/x)*Derivative[1, 0][f][x, w] - r2[x, w]
]]
(* Output: 0. *)
```

So, with a bit of hacking, I think this settles it?

Comment: So in this case your strategy is to look for an exact solution with w as a parameter, then replace w with its value ? Do you think it will work with more complicated functions for r, with definite dependence on w ?

Comment: How bad is `r[x,w]` in general? I mean, if you made it a nightmare, I'm sure `DSolve` could have issues, but you can change to something like `w-ps[x]/2` or even `w^2-(w+1)ps[x]/2` and it works (the solution is a bit more of a mess though). In terms of the Mathematica syntax, this strategy seems relatively effective. I can't comment on whether this is theoretically sound in some way -- I'm not especially familiar with this type of PDE.

Comment: I would say it's pretty bad. In general, r represents the reaction rate and is a complicated function of concentrations and temperatures involving multiple exponentials. A typical expression will look like that :http://image.slidesharecdn.com/methanolsteamreforminginpdagreactorcompletepresentation-12688236180409-phpapp02/95/methanol-steam-reforming-in-pdag-membrane-reactor-for-high-purity-hydrogen-generation-21-728.jpg?cb=1268806247

Comment: Have you tried my code with one of your real `r[x,w]` functions?

Comment: @Whelp I think treating `w` as a parameter is a good idea but I don't see why you couldn't do the same with `NDSolve`. I've added an explanation to my original answer as these comments are character limited.

Comment: @Whelp Have you tried my code with one of your real `r[x,w]` functions? Frankly, whatever it is, if it's too complicated for what I've worked up using `DSolve`, switching to `NDSolve` for more complicated `r[x,w]` does the trick. I'm not sure what else there is to worry about at this point.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

I think that treating `w` as a parameter, like @KellenMyers suggested, is a good idea but you should be able to do that with `NDSolve` as well, not just `DSolve`, in case your actual problem does not have an analytic solution. For example the following should work (note that I've changed the boundary to be at `x=1` and `x=2` instead of `x=0` and `x=1` for reasons that will become apparent)

```
pc[w_] := 5*(1 - 0.01*w);
r[x_, w_] := 1 - ps[x]/2
e[w_] := ps''[x] + 2/x ps'[x] - r[x, w] == 0;
bc1[w_] := ps'[1] == 0;
bc2[w_] := ps'[2] == ps[2] - pc[w];
sol[w_] := First@NDSolve[{e[w], bc1[w], bc2[w]}, ps, {x, 1, 2}];
f[x_, w_] := ps[x] /. sol[w]
```

With your example there is an additional problem that one of the boundary conditions is at `x=0` and if you try to put that there in the above code you'll get an error of division by 0. I think this happens because the solution is a superposition of spherical bessels whose derivatives diverge at the origin like I pointed out previously. It is only by choosing the coefficients so that the divergent part cancels in the limit $x\rightarrow 0$ that get rid of that. Apparently `NDSolve` can't handle that. There's probably a fancy and clever way of circumventing this problem but since I'm neither of those the way I would go about it is by shifting your boundary by a tiny amount $x_0$ which is smaller than the accuracy you want to achieve:

```
pc[w_] := 5*(1 - 0.01*w);
r[x_, w_] := 1 - ps[x]/2
e[w_] := ps''[x] + 2/x ps'[x] - r[x, w] == 0;
bc1[w_, x0_] := ps'[x0] == 0;
bc2[w_] := ps'[1] == ps[1] - pc[w];
sol[w_, x0_] := 
  First@NDSolve[{e[w], bc1[w, x0], bc2[w]}, ps, {x, x0, 1+x0}];
f[x_, w_, x0_] := ps[x + x0] /. sol[w, x0]
```

/EDIT below is my original reply which I later realised was wrong: there is a combination of spherical bessels such that the first derivative doesn't diverge at the origing.

Probably someone else will be able to help you with Mathematica better than I can but, purely on the level of math, it may be worth pointing out that your example is poorly chosen.

Since you don't have any derivatives with respect to `w` the equation is actually just an inhomogeneous Spherical Bessel equation for the variable `x`. The solutions are the 0-order Spherical Bessel functions which diverge at the origin making your boundary conditions impossible.

Comment: Well, the equation is designed to model diffusion/reaction of chemicals inside a catalyst pellet of spherical shape. The boundary conditions describe the absence of particle flow at the center of the pellet (x=0) and at the surface (x=1) the flow is governed by the concentration gradient in the boundary layer. In this, w is a parameter that describe the axial location in a reactor, but the mass transfer I am looking at is only diffusion through the pellet.

Comment: This is basically a version of equation 12-11 p. 6 of this document : http://www.umich.edu/~essen/html/byconcept/chapter12.pdf

Comment: @Whelp I was wrong, actually only one of the spherical bessels diverges at the origin. The analytic solution to your problem is

$$
p_s(x,w)=2+\frac{2-p_c(w)}{\frac{\cos(1/\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}}-2\sin(1/\sqrt{2})}\frac{\sin(x/\sqrt{2})}{x}
$$

so this should be a well defined problem. Please disregard my previous comment.

For some reason LaTeX isn't displayed properly. The last part should be $\frac{\sin(x/\sqrt{2})}{x}$

Comment: Thanks for the correction. At the moment, I'm still unable to get results. The error mesage reads : NDSolve::femcnmd: The PDE coefficient {{2/x,0}} does not evaluate to a numeric matrix of dimensions {1,2}. >>

Comment: @Whelp You should include the error message(s) in your question.  It would be helpful, especially given all the typos.  It's hard to know which problem you were actually facing.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The new error message is now included in my edit.